# How To Drow Radar Chart in Jsp

Tags: jsp, charts, radar-chart

I can make reader chat in swing but how can i draw that chat in jsp 
i am illustrate  my code in this post so how to draw a radar chat in jsp
i am using hexagonal chart

```
import java.awt.*;
import org.jfree.ui.*;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.*;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.*;
import org.jfree.chart.title.*;
import org.jfree.data.category.*;

  public class RadarChart extends ApplicationFrame {
    public DefaultCategoryDataset dataset;
    public SpiderWebPlot plot;

    public RadarChart(String title) {
        super(title);
        String series1 = "First";
        String series2 = "Second";
        String series3 = "Third";

        String category1 = "Task Completion";
        String category2 = "Accuracy";
        String category3 = "Sophistication";
        String category4 = "Listening";
        String category5 = "Pronunciation";

        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        dataset.addValue(5.0, series1, category1);
        dataset.addValue(5.0, series1, category2);
        dataset.addValue(5.0, series1, category3);
        dataset.addValue(5.0, series1, category4);
        dataset.addValue(5.0, series1, category5);

        dataset.addValue(2.0, series2, category1);
        dataset.addValue(4.0, series2, category2);
        dataset.addValue(5.0, series2, category3);
        dataset.addValue(3.0, series2, category4);
        dataset.addValue(5.0, series2, category5);


        SpiderWebPlot plot = new SpiderWebPlot(dataset);

        plot.setStartAngle(90);

        plot.setInteriorGap(0.20);

        plot.setToolTipGenerator(new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator());

        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("", TextTitle.DEFAULT_FONT, plot, false);

        ChartUtilities.applyCurrentTheme(chart);

        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        this.plot = (SpiderWebPlot) chartPanel.getChart().getPlot();
        this.dataset = (DefaultCategoryDataset) plot.getDataset();
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 270));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
                RadarChart demo = new RadarChart("Chart");
                demo.pack();
                RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
                demo.setVisible(true);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) can do radar plots.

Comment: i want to ploat radar haxagonal chart on jsp page so tell me how to do that i can do that on swing but how to create chart on jsp.

Comment: @Nayan: By following the link I just posted and reading about it. I'm not going to spoon-feed it to you.